# Most efficient way to calculate matrix inverse : MATLAB CODE

Tags: matlab

I am looking for the most efficient way to calculate an inverse of a matrix. I know that it has something to do with the LU decomposition, or separating it in two matrix, superior triangular and inferior triangular matrix and the solving the two systems, but I can't work out the code in MATLAB. I don't even know where to start, or how to use the system's results in my problem. 
I really need it because I have to solve a 10.000 X 10.000 matrix and the simple way takes forever.

Comment: Matlab's builtin `inv` is probably about the most efficient you can use. And if you need to solve a linear system, rather than computing the matrix inverse, take a look at `mldivide`

Answer (score 1):

Often a matrix inverse is not really needed to solve a matrix problem. For example, the standard solution of `A x = b`, where `A` is square and non-singular, is often expressed as `x = inv(A) * b`.  But this is not how such a system is solved in practice.

So the naive solution in MATLAB would be:

```
x = inv(A)*b;
```

but the efficient solution would be

```
x = A\b;
```

where the latter uses a number of advanced techniques that do not require an explicit inverse of the matrix `A`.  See [Matrix Inverse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) documentation for details.

Comment: I know, but a lot of people are saying that the best way is to use LU decomposition. What's with that?